# accessing HBase using Java API, the first connection is very slow. Is it normal?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Using Java API, I tried to connect the Hbase server. While getting First connection to Table, it took more than 600ms irrespective of put, scan or getoperations.

For subsequent connection, it took less than 10ms. Why there is huge delay for getting first connection.

Whether I use org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable or org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory for the first connection it took more time compared to subsequent connection. Is it normal?

Below is sample code I used.

```
package sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class InsertData {

    private static String TABLE_NAME = "DATA";
    private static Long Id = 2222L;
    private static String COLUMN_FAMILY = "CF”;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

            Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();


            File folder = new File(“filename”);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    String[] fileSplit = fileName.split("_");
                    byte[] content = readContentIntoByteArray(new File(fileName));
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
                    Table hTable = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));


                    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(Id + "_" + fileSplit[0]));
                    put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(fileSplit[1].substring(0, fileSplit[1].indexOf("."))), content);

                    HTable.validatePut(put, 10000000);

                    hTable.put(put);

                    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    System.out.println("data inserted  " + content.length + " filename " + fileName);

                    hTable.close();
                    connection.close();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static byte[] readContentIntoByteArray(File file) {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try {
            // convert file into array of bytes
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bFile;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
    732
    data inserted  14562 filename 15003_15005.txt
    8
    data inserted  14968 filename 15033_15035.txt
    9
    data inserted  14968 filename 16003_16005.txt
    8
    data inserted  24330 filename 16003_16061.txt
    9
    data inserted  3642 filename 16003_16082.txt
    8
    data inserted  119544 filename 16033_16035.txt
    9
    data inserted  14562 filename 15003_15005.txt
    8
    data inserted  14968 filename 15033_15035.txt
    9
    data inserted  14968 filename 16003_16005.txt
    8
    data inserted  24330 filename 16003_16061.txt
    9
    data inserted  3642 filename 16003_16082.txt
    8
    data inserted  119544 filename 16033_16035.txt
```

Please explain me why it took more time for the first connection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is normal indeed, when you first connect to the database, HBase is creating the object for the connection, bind a port etc etc. Which can take a few ms.

However as specified in the [HBase reference guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html) connections are heavyweight, so it is a best practice to create only one at the beginning of your app and keep it running all the process long.

You will tell me, that you are creating a new one each loop, indeed, but I think HBase has already what is necessary to create a new Connection, and as you just deleted one and recreate it, it doesn't recreate everything.

That's my point of view and I think it's the most logical way. Try creating a connection before your loop and keep it running all the process, and you should have consistency in your puts.